# log4j properties file is not picking up from war file

Tags: jboss, log4j, portlet, jsr

I have created a webapplication and deployed in jboss server.

I placed log4j.properties file in WEB-INF/classes folder. But instead of using my application specific log4j.properties, it is using default log4j.properties and printing the logs in server.log.

When do I need to place the log4j.properties to be picked up? My war file is a JSR portlet, so I cannot use static method to read the properties file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

3 step guide to setup your own log4j for jboss 4.2

1: place your `log4j.properties` on classpath of your WAR/EAR

2: place your `log4j.jar` in your classpath

3: isolate classloader using `jboss-web.xml` to use your copy of jar for your application

for detailed steps refer to this article : [how to use custom log4j](http://planet.jboss.org/post/how_do_i_use_my_own_log4j_properties_or_xml_file_in_jboss)